# Sliding button or text across the screen

Tags: android

Sometimes you see in android applications that the move the button from one side of the screen to another (cosmetic stuffs) and it looks nice. Kind of like powerpoint presentation when you slide in text.

I was wondering, are these done typically using Animations in android classes or is it moved using coordinates/draw function in a loop. I am not sure which way is typically this done.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you mean (maybe you can give a specific example/app), but usually you use the [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) class to create an animation. There are some specific animations (subclasses) that can be used, but you can also create your own (by subclassing or via xml).

The one you describe sounds like the TranslateAnimation, that just translates the coordinates of a view at the beginning of an animation to coordinates at the end of the animation.

Also take a look here, for further reference.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: Thank you.. What I mean, is you know when you pause a game then the pause dialog shows up and it slides from left to center. Kind of like giving it nice looking. That's what I was referring tok